# SpellCheck is Not Working WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

I am working on one WPF application. In that i need to enable spell checking on text box and it should work properly according to ENGLISH(Australia).Here's what i have done.

`<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-GB"  />`

The thing is it's working as expected in my system but if i run same code in other user's system it's not working like it does in my system.

For example in my system if i type Color it displays in red and Colour is detected as correct. which is correct for australian english. where as in other user's system it displays red in Colour. So what makes this diffrence ??

Note : .NetFramework version 4.6.1.

some are saying some language pack needs to be installed. but i have not installed any in my system though it's working.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c4a62da5-9a7d-4e1d-bcbc-12945046fc42/textbox-spellcheckisenabled-not-working-in-wpf-4?forum=wpf

So what's wrong in other user's system ?

Comment: Maybe users machine is set to American English for keyboard and UI, have you checked zone settings?

Comment: Yes, I've checked keyboard and Language as well as zone settings. It's set to English(Australia).Also Even if i set it to English(US) in my system it works. but in other system it doesn't work for any(US/Australia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay It worked in other user's system after setting Language Preference and default language to Australia and restarting system. although it always say "colour" correct and color wrong.even if Language is en-US or en-GB or en.